# Сайт под все разрешения

Tags: html, вёрстка, css

Что нужно сделать, чтобы сделанный сайт корректно отображался во всех разрешениях экрана? 
Начиная с 1024 и далее.

Answer (score 9):

делаете обёртку, в которой будет находиться остальная разметка

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <!-- тут остальной код -->
    </div>
</body>
```

И прописываете в CSS для неё стиль

```
#wrapper {
     width: 100%;
     min-width: 980px;
}
```

P.S. Для IE6 не помешает фикс в отдельном файле, который подключите условным коментарием. Напрмер так:

```
<!--[if lte IE 6]><link rel="stylesheet" href="style_ie.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection" /><![endif]-->
```

Стиль внутри style_ie.css:

```
* html #wrapper {
    width: expression((documentElement.clientWidth||document.body.clientWidth)<980?'980px':'');
}
```